# What is the name for a question that decides what further questions to ask?

Tags: single-word-requests, questions

I am struggling to come up with what this would be called, but it feels like there is almost certainly a word/phrase for it. For example, let's say we have a survey and the first question is a yes or no type question. Answering yes may lead to just one more question, while answering no would lead to two more questions, one of which being another yes or no type question, the other wanting some sort of other answer that the survey taker can fill in. If the second yes is taken, the survey is complete, but if the second no is taken, even more questions could be asked until the survey reaches its final question.

Is there a name for the yes or no questions that essentially direct the survey taker down whichever path makes sense for the survey taker given their input?

Edit: I should also note that there are not always two possible answers, although my example only included two answer questions. Another possible "answer set" could be less than, the same as, greater than, for some question asking about frequency of something happening.

Comment: A preliminary question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was working as a QM for some local BPO's, we used to use [SurveyMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SurveyMonkey) to create formats like that.

It is sometimes referred to as...

***skip logic***

> Skip logic is a feature that changes what question or page a respondent sees next based on how they answer the current question. Also known as **“conditional branching”** or “**branch logic,”** skip logic creates a custom path through the survey that varies based on a respondent’s answers. This skip pattern will vary based on rules that you define for the respondent.

[-SurveyMonkey.com](https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/tour/skiplogic/)

The *particular type* of question is often called a..

***Branching Question***

> A question used to guide an interviewer through a survey to different questions (i.e. skipping some questions), depending on the answers given.

[-Insights Association](https://www.insightsassociation.org/issues-policies/glossary/branching-question)

Comment: funny anecdote, but once we were getting a lot of complaints about automated answering service, and I decided to investigate. After 45 minutes the call finally redirected back to the starting question, no doubt pissing off  lot of customers who did not complain. I documented the situation and created a flow-chart and sent it to upper management. The AAS was discontinued until major changes were made